# The "reverse operation" of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

It is possible to adjoin an element $\alpha$ to a field $\mathbb{F}$. Is there a name for the operation to take away an element $\alpha$ (and all subsequent elements) from a field $\mathbb{F}$ to form a subfield $\mathbb{E}$?

I came across this notion when trying to visualize the field $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_2$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. The closure is formed by consecutively adjoining roots of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or some extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. However, there are infinitely such polynomials, and thus infinitely such roots to adjoin, which makes it hard to visualize. I think it may be interesting trying to take away elements from $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_2$ instead.

Comment: Let $K = \Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ then $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\Bbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$ are the maximal subfields not containing $i$. The general case can be treated in term of Galois theory and minimal subgroup containing representatives of a quotient group

Comment: Your statement for the finite field seems intuitive but I don't really know how to prove it. I see that we can start with two different maximal subfields not containing a, but I can't really reach a contradiction. On the other hand, what do you think about the statement for infinite fields?

Comment: I meant that for a finite field it is **not** always unique :) let $a$ such that $\Bbb{F}_p(a) = \Bbb{F}_{p^6}$, the maximal subfields are $\Bbb{F}_{p^2},\Bbb{F}_{p^3}$

Comment: Let me use the more unambiguous notations, $\Bbb F_p$ for the field with $p$ elements, and $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ for its algebraic closure. I hope you’re not thinking that by “removing an element” from $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ you’ll get a field $K$ with $[\overline{\Bbb F_p}:K]<\infty$, because there are no such fields $K$.